# How long will a rollback version of a basic package be supported?

Tags: packages

Edit: many softwares have detailed support policies for old releases. But I don't find anything about packages maintained by LaTeX team. Am I wrong to ask this question?

For example, there are two rollback versions for `array` package: `array-2016-10-06.sty` and
`array-2020-02-10.sty`. Will these files be updated if they can not run in a future release of LaTeX kernel? And how long will they be supported?

Comment: you could ask the same about any package on ctan, mostly new latex releases don't break them but of they do someone somwhere will update, that's how open source works. Actually thse files are used in places in the latex test suite so for the ones in tools they will be supported for as long as tools is supported, most likely but the future is the future

Comment: I voted to close as opinion based as if I don't know the answer and I'm co-author of that package, no one else is likely to know more.

Comment: Should I edit the question and emphasis the packages maintained by LaTeX team?

Comment: well as I say I can't even answer this for packages maintained by me. But there is nothing special about the dated rollback versions, they are as supported as any other file including the current array.sty

Comment: in relation to your edit this isn't an "old release" that is, if someone finds a bug in latex or array.sty from say 2019 we will never release an updated version of that distribution say "2019/01/01 patch level 16" in that sense old releases are frozen/unsupported.  the file array-2016-10-06.sty is part of the _current_ latex release and is as supported as any other file in that release.

Comment: From your comments, I think, at least for this time, the answer from the LaTeX team is 'forever'?

Comment: The files will  probably not be removed, but it is quite unclear if there will have any use in 5 or 10 years. What is your use case?

Comment: My `tabularray` package will have a rollback version from a new release with breaking changes next year. And I don't know how long should I support the old release. Time is limited for me but the kernel keeps moving on...

Comment: you shouldn't really expect a package to break with a new latex release so your rollback version can offer your users your existing (old) interface with the undated version offering a new interface. If in the future a latex change breaks the rollback version and you don't have time to fix it the latex team may fix it (it has a firstaid mechansim for exactly such things) or some keen user might or anything else may happen.  it is reasonable to assume it won't happen, and if it does, something will work out.

Comment: OK, maybe I am overthinking it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this, like many other questions here, seems a perfectly legitimate question with an objective answer (given as comments). I struggle to understand the definition of "opinion based" used on SE sites. I have no superpowers but I know an objective question when I see one. This opinion based definition of "opinion based" has kept me from asking many, many questions lest they be closed.

Comment: There is no guarantee that outdated package versions will be supported.  However, if a package is being actively maintained, you can contact the maintainer to request some feature of backward compatibility (or new feature).  Depending on how difficult that may or may not be, the maintainer may strive to satisfy your request. I have had package maintainers provide features at my request  (Don Arseneau gave me `\TabPrevPos` in the `tabto` package, for example) and I have on occasion provided users features at their request on packages I support.